# Making Footer Always At Bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that the footer of my website is ALWAYS at the bottom of the web page. No matter if the web page content is too small to occupy the entire screen or if it has so much content that you need to scroll the footer should always be at the bottom of the screen... For example... I've made the following code to help demonstrate the issue...

The issue is that while there is only one "Placeholder" div, the footer is simply pushed under it (it should be at the very bottom of the page like what happens when all Placeholders are uncommented).

How can I achieve this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.Placeholder
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.MyFooter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='Header'>Header</div>
    <div class="MainContainer">
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <!-- Uncomment these to populate the container.
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      !-->   
    </div>
    <div class="MyFooter">
      This is my footer, it should always be at the bottom of the page.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make .MyFooter {position: fixed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add is

```
html, body{
height: 100%;
}
```

That should fix the problem

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html, body{
height: 100%;
}

.Placeholder
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.MyFooter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='Header'>Header</div>
    <div class="MainContainer">
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <!-- Uncomment these to populate the container.
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      !-->   
    </div>
    <div class="MyFooter">
      This is my footer, it should always be at the bottom of the page.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: or make .MyFooter {position: fixed;

Comment: This worked, but is there a way in CSS to make the footer's bottom element be 0 if theres no content and auto if there is content?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the body height. Try adding `height: 100vh;` to your `body` CSS class.

Comment: That didn't change anything, but the height of the body is already set to 100% (min-height: 100%;).

Comment: Change `body min-height:` to `100vh`

Comment: The use of `100vh` is how I would approach this as well. Try adding `.MainContainer { min-height: 100vh;}` or even offset the height of the header, assuming the header has a min height of 30px via: `.MainContainer { min-height: calc(100vh - 30px); }`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed footer use `position: fixed`

Here is an example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.Placeholder
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.MyFooter {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1030;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='Header'>Header</div>
    <div class="MainContainer">
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <!-- Uncomment these to populate the container.
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      !-->   
    </div>
    <div class="MyFooter">
      This is my footer, it should always be at the bottom of the page.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you had to change was the value of the position. the correct one for what you are looking for is position: fixed

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.Placeholder
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

footer {
 background-color: red;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='Header'>Header</div>
    <div class="MainContainer">
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <!-- Uncomment these to populate the container.
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      <div class='Placeholder'></div>
      !-->   
    </div>
    <footer>
      This is my footer, it should always be at the bottom of the page.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Position fixed makes the footer always there, not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go and read about [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) of elements once. All the best. A very small change can help you here, Just change the position of your **MyFooter** class. i.e.

```css
.MyFooter {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Fixed would make the footer always on the screen, I want it at the bottom of the page content when there is lots of content or bottom of the screen when there is not enough content to fill the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom: 0` and `bottom: auto` to fix this.
But first, you should set the body's height to 100% so that the footer can stay in the bottom of the page when there is one "placeholder".
Here is the code, with just one "placeholder": (`bottom: 0px;`)

```js
let h = window.innerHeight;

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.style = "height: " + h + "px;";

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    h = window.innerHeight;
    x.style = "height: " + h + "px;";
});

if(document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight > h) {
  document.getElementById('footer').style = "bottom: auto;";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Placeholder
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.MyFooter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='Header'>Header</div>
  <div class="MainContainer" id="main">
    <div class='Placeholder'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="MyFooter" id="footer">
    This is my footer, it should always be at the bottom of the page.
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is the code, with all the "placeholders": (`bottom: auto;`)

```js
let h = window.innerHeight;

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.style = "height: " + h + "px;";

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    h = window.innerHeight;
    x.style = "height: " + h + "px;";
});

if(document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight > h) {
  document.getElementById('footer').style = "bottom: auto;";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Placeholder
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.MainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.MyFooter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='Header'>Header</div>
  <div class="MainContainer" id="main">
    <div class='Placeholder'></div>
    <div class='Placeholder'></div>
    <div class='Placeholder'></div>
    <div class='Placeholder'></div>
    <div class='Placeholder'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="MyFooter" id="footer">
    This is my footer, it should always be at the bottom of the page.
  </div>
</body>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/xxGmqaY